# Why is it not recommended to have logic in a stateful widget's createState method?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have can create a stateful widget as follows: `MyAxisWidget(axis: someAxis)`, where `someAxis` is of type `Axis`.

Next, I want the implementation of the widget to depend on the specified axis. That is I have two `State<MyAxisWidget>` classes for the corresponding axis. In the `createState` method, I would write:

```
@override
State<MyAxisWidget> createState() =>
    axis == Axis.horizontal ? MyHorizontalAxisWidgetState() : MyVerticalAxisWidgetState();
```

This violates a linter rule: [no_logic_in_create_state](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/no_logic_in_create_state)

While the docs state that we shouldn't do it, it doesn't explicitly tell me why exactly it is bad to do it. I don't understand what semantic difference it makes in the framework, what the drawbacks are, etc. leading to the reason behind that rule.

The simple solution would be to instantiate the implementation class in `initState` and defer to it where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) documentation:

> [...] StatefulWidget instances themselves are immutable and store their mutable state either in separate State objects that are created by the createState method [...]

When creating the state, you only have access to values received by the Stateful Widget constructor. In your example, `someAxis`. Since this is passed in the constructor, it is going to be immutable.

Let's go step by step:

- Firstly, the lint rule is addressing the passage of parameters in the constructor of the State class. It doesn't feel right to have an *immutable* field stored in the `State` class which should hold information about how the state changes and how these changes reflect in the widget's behavior.
- From the [createState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget/createState.html) documentation, we see that:

> The framework can call this method multiple times over the lifetime of a StatefulWidget. For example, if the widget is inserted into the tree in multiple locations, the framework will create a separate State object for each location. Similarly, if the widget is removed from the tree and later inserted into the tree again, the framework will call createState again to create a fresh State object, simplifying the lifecycle of State objects.

which is the reason you should always return a new instance. Since it is supposed to be called multiple times, it is also why you should keep the logic of the `createState` as minimal as possible. In your example, your logic is just an `if` statement, which isn't too heavy, but the lint can't measure so it considers a violation. *Even if your logic is only an if statement*, it feels better to encapsulate all of the logic about how the widget is going to behave in the same place. In this case, inside the widget State class.

There are a few approaches you could do instead:

- If the widget implementation is similar in both cases, you can create an Extension on `Axis` enum (or a helper method):

```dart
extension YourExtension on Axis {
  String get title {
    switch (this) {
      case Axis.horizontal:
        return 'Title horizontal';
      case Axis.vertical:
        return 'Title Vertical';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}
 // Or, as an alternative:
String helperMethodTitle(Axis axis) {
    return Axis.horizontal == axis ? 'Title 1' : 'Title 2';
}
```

and call it whenever you need it inside the State Class: `widget.axis.title`.

If the implementation on both cases is too different, it may make sense to have two different stateful widgets, and call whatever is correct:

```dart
[...]
child: Axis.horizontal? HorizontalMyAxisWidget() : VerticalMyAxisWidget()
[...]
```

Well, ultimately, lint rules are only preferences of a coding style over another. They are not mandatory to follow it if you don't want to.